# Segmentation fault when schedule R script with airflow

Tags: r, airflow

I use Airflow (docker container) to run an R script. I get the following error.

```
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,500] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  *** caught segfault ***
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,500] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - address 0x55cf00000000, cause 'memory not mapped'
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,501] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - 
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,501] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - Traceback:
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,501] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  1: is.data.frame(x)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,502] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  2: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,502] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  3: lapply(.x, .f, ...)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,502] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  4: map(result, subset_rows, i)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,502] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  5: `[.tbl_df`(x, ind, , drop = FALSE)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,503] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  6: x[ind, , drop = FALSE]
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,503] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  7: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,504] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  8: lapply(split(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...),     function(ind) x[ind, , drop = FALSE])
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,505] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  9: split.data.frame(es6, (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50))
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,505] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - 10: split(es6, (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50))
[2019-09-19 07:03:26,506] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
[2019-09-19 07:03:27,087] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmpuj8lcw3e/web_etl_bf_10_days7wpo7bvb: line 1:  1140 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) Rscript /usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/r/etl_web_api_by_create_time.R -d "2019-09-05 00:00:00+00:00"
[2019-09-19 07:03:27,088] {{bash_operator.py:131}} INFO - Command exited with return code 139
```

The code with error is `split(es6, (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50))`. The data frame es6 has about 1096 rows and 20 columns.

I can't reproduce the error it sometime success and failed other times with Airflow. (And the code works when I run it through Rstudio Sever.)

I suspect low memory in my sever may be the cause. My linux sever has 8GB memory in total. When I check the memory when runing the task, it has about 1700MB available (using `free -m` command).

I searched the internet and someone suggest this kind of error may be caused by the bug of the function, i.e., `split`.

Edit:

After change to `split(as.data.frame(es6), (0:(nrow(es6)-1) %/% 50))`. The new log:

```
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,652] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  *** caught segfault ***
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,652] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - address 0x55f600000000, cause 'memory not mapped'
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,652] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - 
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,652] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - Traceback:
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,652] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  1: dim(xj)
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  2: `[.data.frame`(x, ind, , drop = FALSE)
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  3: x[ind, , drop = FALSE]
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  5: lapply(split(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...),     function(ind) x[ind, , drop = FALSE])
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  6: split.data.frame(as.data.frame(es6), (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50))
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -  7: split(as.data.frame(es6), (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50))
[2019-09-19 09:17:22,653] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
[2019-09-19 09:17:23,179] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp9jy2rurg/web_etl_bf_7_days4x9d7xqz: line 1:  1220 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) Rscript /usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/r/etl_web_api_by_create_time.R -d "2019-09-10 00:00:00+00:00"
[2019-09-19 09:17:23,179] {{bash_operator.py:131}} INFO - Command exited with return code 139
```

Comment: The traceback info shows that the segfault seems to happen when `is.data.frame` is called. Which is extremely unlikely to be the culprit. However, you seem to actually dealing with a tibble? If there is a bug it is most likely related to that. Can you try `split(as.data.frame(es6), (0:(nrow(es6) - 1)%/%50)))`?

Comment: @Roland After add `as.data.frame`, there is one success and one failed. I edit the post to add the new log.